# How to send a flag/data as an input to installed android app?

Tags: android

Is there a way to send a flag or a single number or character to my app running on a device using android developer console or by using any other way, without touching the mobile device?

**Example :**
Say I have a mobile. I install my app-test.apk in the device by downloading it from google play or by transferring it to the sd card.
Now the app is running in my mobile.
What I want is to send a message/a flag/a number/a character or anything to the app **so that the app identifies it and perform some action**, some sort of a trigger for some condition. *Like app shows a toast messages saying "I am running"*.  All this without touching the device.
If it is not possible how can I achieve this by just shaking the device or pressing the volume button with device in locked state or by minimal touching the device ?
Is this possible ?

Thanks !

Comment: what exactly you want to do after sending flag?

Comment: anything like showing a toast message or any business logic

Comment: or more particularly, say my app syncs the call logs every 24 hours but I want it now so just send that flag to get the logs now

Comment: @iAmLearning create custome broadcastreceiver in app and send action

Comment: but where from will I send it ?

Comment: Using `adb shell`.

Comment: as per https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html
both the devices should be connected to the same wifi network to send the commands using adb shell. right ?

Comment: wait but that too is possible with android wearables only... isn't it ?